# symfony2 doctrine annotation [Semantical Error]

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine-orm

I using symfony2 and doctrine and I am getting the following error:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\RuleId" in property Wibiya\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Rules::$RuleId does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

The `Rules` entity contain the column/field in it.

```php
    /**
     * @var integer $RuleId
     * @ORM\RuleId
     * @ORM\Column(name="RuleId", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $RuleId;
```

This is the function I am trying to run:

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$Rules = $em->getRepository('WibiyaWebsiteBundle:Rules')->findAllOrderedByName();
```

The `RulesRepository` class:

```php
    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM WibiyaWebsiteBundle:Rules p ORDER BY p.RuleName ASC')
            ->getResult();
    }
```

I tried to put this line at the bottom of the `autoload.php`:

```php
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php";
```

But, I got the same error.
I'm using Symfony 2.0.16 and Doctrine 2.1.6

Answer (score 3):

There is no `RuleId` annotation in Doctrine, just `Id` [[see docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/namespace-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.html)].

Just use `@ORM\Id` on the primary key field **all** entities you define.

Comment: The issue is solved, thanks for the answer, by the way, how do I set primary key other than Id?

Answer (score 0):

`@ORM\Id` is just annotation for your primary key field in doctrine mapping, its independent of column name of primary key in your MySql table. You can keep any name for your primary key field and specify it on mapping as `@ORM\Column(name="column_name", type="integer")`.